# Use last rows for suggesting types in SQL Server 2008 R2 Import Wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, text-manipulation

I use SQL Server to locally store data for statistical analysis. I create my tables from csv files that typically have hundreds of columns. Manually prescribing column names and types would be tedious, so I use "suggest types" in the Import Wizard to pick the correct type.

This works most of the time, but frequently my csv files have a "ragged top edge" (i.e., a lot of the columns are empty for the first thousand or million lines -- a lot of these files are 1+ gb, thus the need for SQL Server to facilitate subsetting joining). Because the Import Wizard only looks at up to the first 1000 rows, this can fail my import. Is there a clever workaround?

The solution I can think of is to move the last thousand or so rows to the top of the file,  just below the header row. But since some of these files are 1+ gb with millions of rows, I can't do in a text editor. Is there a way that I can outsmart the Import Wizard? Or read backwards? Or move the last thousand or so lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't set in the wizard but you can if you do it as a full SSIS solution.
And/or the row limit of 1000 is a bug in SQL Server 2008 (not sure about R2)

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/2354ca36-9c2a-4a08-b22c-59a511d302c1) for more

I have set this sample rows myself at some point but can't remember when and what version/SP level I used.

Comment: @gbn -- I can't follow your link. Can I use SSIS with the free academic version? Thanks!

Comment: @richardh: sorry, dodgy copy/paste. Fixed it. And yes, I think you can use it

Comment: @gbn -- Thanks! I had found this. I don't have a program called SSIS, so I may be limited to a text manipulation solution.

Comment: Ssis is a visual studio add in installed with SQL server as the "BIDS" option... VS express is also installed

Comment: @gbn -- OK, thanks, I found it. It is pretty overwhelming, but I should be able to figure something out.

Comment: I don't think there's a work-around. The best you can do is get close with the wizard and then use trial and error. Another problem that arises with this method is NULL values are ignored and replaced with 0. The solution here is to use the wizard to create the .dtsx files, then manually edit to accept NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the header rows to skip until you get the expected result.

I'd be incrementing the Header rows to skip by 1000 or so then reduce it to make sure I haven't missed anything until I can get a decent preview of the data. Not tried this on such a large file, but can't see why it wouldn't work on a decent machine.

If you want something less tedious, a simple batch file or console app could remove whitespace from these files. Just make sure it uses the correct textreader approach to ensure it's reading single lines instead of trying to load the whole file in memory.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I am not sure that I can combine this option with the use header option.

Comment: Suggesting different options. The batch/console app approach would just be to "clean" your files before importing them as you currently are. Should be pretty straight forward to remove the extra linebreaks or even empty rows without loading the full file in memory. It's not perfect, but means 1 click clean then as you are doing it now.

Comment: I would like to keep the incomplete entries. If the files were smaller, moving a few thousand lines would be easy in Vim. I think I need a command line solution, even if it's to delete the first million entries and add later, but that's outside my wheelhouse. Is there a language or command that makes this possible?